# Specifying VisualStateGroups in a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to redefine the look of the selected item of a ListView (Metro-style application).

I achieved it by defining `VisualStateGroups` in my template.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="expenseItem" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>

    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemLocationName" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ExpenseListHighlightedText}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="expenseItem" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationGradientBlue}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

My problem is that when I put my cursor over the selected item, the background changes, even if I don't want that. And when I move out, the item get the "normal" background instead of keeping the "selected" background.

How do I specify that the background must not change on the selected item?

*Edit:* I still want to have to over effect to item that are not selected.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the storyboard from the PointerOver state.

Comment: I want to keep this Over effect to non-selected items on the list.